# Timer library in Arduino

Tags: timer, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm doing a calculator with arduino 4x4 keypad and 16x2 LCD. I have to do timer-interupt for this project with timer library. I asked this Q before, but I did not know that I must use timer library. Here is my Q : If an user does not press one of the button on keypad for 30 secs, the calculator should close itself. How can I do that with timer library ?

Comment: So, you already know how to "close" it: the timer event will just perform a `digitalWrite()` to the pin shutting down itself - you need an external circuit for this. You need to register a callback with `after()` after 30 seconds and you need to reschedule it, at any keypress, by invoking probably `stop()` on the event id and `after()` again. Does it works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timer library, you could use the millis() function:

```
    // setup

long int time;

void loop(){
 // get input
 if(input){
  interpretInput(input); // For example
  time = millis();
 }
 if(millis()>time+30000){    // if there is more than 30 seconds between now and the last input, then call your shutdown function
  shutdown();
 }
}
```